AWS CodeDeploy Agent cannot download GitHub bundle
I followed the instructions here to setup a GitHub Actions->Code Deploy AWS pipeline:
https://loisthash.medium.com/ci-cd-from-github-to-aws-ec2-667e6c4f4ffc
I get this error:
2024-11-11T20:56:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(26727)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.01756 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{"error_code":5,"script_name":"","message":"Could not download bundle at 'https://api.github.com/repos//deployment-test/tarball/2ca6270054db4d62621f020b88f804fe0fa39c40' after 3 retries. Server returned codes: 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'.","log":""}"})
The repo is in a GitHub organization but I have opened Third Party access per the instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-partners-github.html#github-integ-behaviors-auth
Out of other ideas.

You need to ensure that the PAT (Personal access token) used for the GitHub connection includes the correct scopes:
•   repo (for private repositories)
•   admin:repo_hook (for webhook and services management)
•   read:org (if your organization restricts repository access)

following the two links, you've provided, only this detail is missed in the medium article, so probably you didn't add the correct scopes.
